# NPE when trying to load a json file in Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, processing, geojson

I am working with Processing 2.1, a language built on top of Java that allows the creation of visualizations. Currently I am experimenting with reading in geoJSON files and displaying this information on a map.

I am coding from within the IDE provided by the Processing.org website. It is very primitive in the sense that it does not have the ability to debug the code. It will return errors but I cannot go into my code to find out my problems.

I am currently getting this error: NullPointerException

That's it, I am told of nothing else bar the line it occurs at.

```
  List<Feature> counties = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "ireland.geo.json");
```

I do not understand why I am getting it. The file I am trying to read exists. Could anyone please help me with this issue?

Below is my complete code:

```
    UnfoldingMap map;
List<Marker>countyMarkers;
List<Marker>countyMarkers2;
color c1 = color(204, 153, 0);

void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  smooth(); 
  //Map
  map = new UnfoldingMap(this);
  MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this, map);
  List<Feature> counties = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "ireland.geo.json");
  countyMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(counties);
  map.addMarkers(countyMarkers);
}

void draw() {
  map.draw();

  for (int i = 0; i < countyMarkers.size(); i++) {
      Marker county = countyMarkers.get(i);
                county.setColor(c1);

      if (county.isInside(map, mouseX, mouseY)) {
        county.draw(map);
        HashMap countyProps = county.getProperties();
        String countyName = countyProps.get("city").toString();
        println(countyName);
      }
  }


}
```

Comment: Show us what `loadData` does.

Comment: It's provided by a Library I am using. I did not write this method. The documentation for the method is here http://unfoldingmaps.org/javadoc/de/fhpotsdam/unfolding/data/GeoJSONReader.html and it basically just does "Parses a GeoJSON String and creates features for them.
"

Comment: Try providing an absolute path to the file.

Comment: I will try that but interestingly, I have a number of geoJSON files in this directory and there is no NPE generated when I try to load them into the program, only this particular one.

Comment: Maybe the JSON is malformed and `loadData` just has bad exception handling.

Comment: I am starting to think that might be the case.

Comment: You can check the JSON on sites like `jsonlint.com`.

Comment: Juat checked there and told it is valid JSON.

Comment: You get no exception traceback???

Comment: You might try a different IDE like Eclipse.  I don't know if they've fixed it, but back when I was using the Processing IDE, there was a bug that rendered the line numbers incorrect, so you might be looking at the wrong line.

Comment: @Javacadabra The Processing IDE was designed with beginners in mind, I strongly suggest you to get [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) and the [Processing-Sublime package](https://github.com/b-g/processing-sublime). You can also add [Processing-like auto indent](http://nicksantan.com/blog/2012/12/adding-auto-format-code-indenting-to-sublime-text-2/). The white of the P5 editor was starting to burn my eyes x_x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer of Unfolding here.

This is due to our JSON parser only handling basics of the Geo JSON specification. (See http://unfoldingmaps.org/tutorials/markers-data-geojson.html )

You can work around this by implementing the parsing yourself with Processing's loadJSONArray and loadJSONObject methods.

*Addendum: While you did not provide your json file, I found one for Ireland's counties, and it could be because of the empty properties in that file. Please try out this version of Unfolding which now handles this without throwing an NPE.*
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/599609/Unfolding_for_processing_0.9.5.1.zip
*If that was not the reason please provide your JSON file so I can check.*

Comment: That did the job! Thank you very much for your help!